# Root Domain not allowed in Azure Static APp

Tags: azure, dns, azure-static-web-app

I am not sure if I am doing this correctly but what I wanted is add a custom domain to my app in a Static Web App in Azure. Unfortunately in the Static app it only accept a custom domain with www on the start (lets pretend the domain I purchase is [www.myperson.com](http://www.myperson.com)), what I was looking for is how to add the root domain to it.

I tried to research and what I did is this on my DNS host site I created bunch of CNAME. The first CNAME I created is

```
Type: CNAME
Name: @ 
Value: azurestatickurl
TTL: Automatic
Cloud: Orange
```

And after that I created another CNAME

```
Type: CNAME
Name: www
Value: @
TTL: Automatic
Cloud: Orange
```

But on the Azure side on the Static web app I created it doesnt validate the url myperson.com and still only accepts [www.myperson.com](http://www.myperson.com)

Please advise on what should I try next. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static Web Apps is currently in preview and root domain support is not available during preview, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain#configure-a-root-domain).

You can see the blog post [Configure root domains in Azure Static Web Apps](https://burkeholland.github.io/posts/static-app-root-domain/) for details on how to configure root domain support with a Static Web App. You can make it work with a little bit of DNS trickery and the help of Cloudflare.

Answer (score 3):

Azure Static App is made [generally available](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/develop-production-scale-modern-web-apps-quickly-with-azure-static-web-apps/) now and they have also added the feature to add root domain to your app.

Check out the following documentation: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain?tabs=azure-dns#add-domain-using-txt-record-validation

---

Below are steps:

1. Go to Custom Domains section in your Static Web App and click "Add"
   button.
2. Ensure that the "Hostname record type" dropdown is set to
   "TXT".
3. Select the Generate code button.
   This action generates a unique code, which may take up to a minute to
   process.
4. Select the clipboard icon next to the code to copy the value to your
   clipboard.
5. Open your Azure DNS Zone.
6. Select the + Record Set button.
7. Create a new TXT record set with the following values.

   ```
   Setting     Value
   Name        @
   Type        TXT
   TTL         Leave as default value
   TTL Unit    Leave as default value
   Value       Paste the code from your clipboard
   ```
8. Select OK.

Comment: Just to add, after finishing above's steps, back into static web app's custom domains, follow instructions at link at the right of added domain https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain?wt.mc_id=azurestaticwebapps_inline_inproduct_general&tabs=azure-dns#create-an-alias-record, they basically ask for adding an A record at dns zone. After doing that, new cust domain worked.